# Parse JSON string to dynamic object without creating class using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

The JSON string that I want to parse is the response from the API and the response may not have fixed properties. So cannot create a class with properties to parse the JSON string.

I tried to parse the JSON string to dynamic/Expando object but it does not parse the nested objects,

For example,

```
string jsonText = "[{ \"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"K\",\"Address\":{\"Line1\":\"Sector 6\"} }]";
```

I am using the below code for deserializing the JSON string,

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this string str) where T : class
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
            {
                UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
                IgnoreExtensionDataObject=true
                
            });
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)))
            {
                return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            }
        }

IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> contactObject = Deserialize<IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>>(jsonText);
```

This code fails to parse the Address property. It simply shows the object instead of the actual value.

[image]

Due to project requirement cannot use NewtonsoftJSON and System.Text.Json.

How I can parse complex JSON string to dynamic object without creating a custom class using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json?

Comment: "Due to project requirement cannot use NewtonsoftJSON and System.Text.Json." When the right tool is a hammer, don't listen to people who won't let you use one. Even MS recommends; "For most scenarios that involve serializing to JSON and deserializing from JSON, we recommend the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav, based on what I test your code in [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fyaJ6Y), I don't think there is any issue as I can able to retrieve the value from Address.

Comment: Hi @YongShun, thanks for your response.  I can see that you have created a class and property for Address and Line1. As I mentioned before, I can have any properties so cannot have a class. Looking for a dynamic approach.